# Daemon isn't interacting with notify-send

Tags: c++, c, linux, ipc, daemon

Here is my code

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid, sid;
    int sec = 10;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pid > 0) {
        std::cout << "Running with PID: " << pid << std::endl;      
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    umask(0);        

    sid = setsid();
    if (sid < 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if ((chdir("/")) < 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    /* Log the failure */

    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);

    while (1) {
        execl("/bin/notify-send", "notify-send", "-t", "3000", "Title", "body", NULL);
        sleep(sec); 
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I want it to give a [notification](http://www.google.com/url?source=imglanding&ct=img&q=http://hackadaycom.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/simple_linux_notifications.jpg&sa=X&ei=6r6wT6PRCM7trQfnxMHmAw&ved=0CAkQ8wc&usg=AFQjCNEt1G1S1zrJqpS8u3Mi1t1HItylNg) in every 10 sec. Daemon is running OK, but not giving any notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execl` doesn't return - it replaces the running program with a new one. So running it in a loop with `sleep` is meaningless - it will run only once.

I think you should use `system` instead. It executes a command and returns.

The alternative is to `fork` each time in the loop, and have the child do `execl` while the parent would continue the loop.

Comment: I don't see a problem running it in a daemon. `system` is affected by environment variables, so if someone can change your daemon's environment, he can cause trouble. But users shouldn't have access to a system daemon's environment.